# Pandas Dataframe: selecting multiple column by value does not work, why?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I build a Dataframe from an sql query (data for may 2014 to june 2015) and try to build 2 different data sets
- train uses all data except June 2015
- test uses only data for June 2015
When I try to use :
train= df[(df.month!=6) & (df.year!=2015)]

It seems that I am using OR instead of AND, because I do not get any values for month=6 (also not for 2014) and no values for year=2015 at all, so also not for other months in 2015.

I do not understand what is wrong with the code.

```
mycurs.execute("""SELECT day, month, year, cloudcover, moonphase, precipintensity,
precipaccumulation, preciptype2, humidity, pressure, windspeed,
uvindex, visibility, temperaturehigh, weekend_2, crimecount
FROM open.nyc_weatherhist_2""")
f=mycurs.fetchall() #returns tuple with first row (unordered list)

df=pd.DataFrame(f, columns=feature_names)
print(df)
```

```
     day  month  year  ...  temperaturehigh  weekend  crimecount
0     28      4  2015  ...            20.85        0          56
1     14      4  2015  ...            18.25        0         103
2     13      7  2014  ...            27.44        0          89
3      4      1  2015  ...            12.94        0          99
4     21      9  2014  ...            24.15        0          66
..   ...    ...   ...  ...              ...      ...         ...
390    4      7  2014  ...            23.37        1          84
391    8      8  2014  ...            27.98        1          97
392   26      4  2015  ...            15.78        0          82
393    3      8  2014  ...            24.50        0          80
394    5      6  2015  ...            20.65        1          87

[395 rows x 16 columns]
```

```
train= df[(df.month!=6) & (df.year!=2015)]
print(train)
```

```
     day  month  year  ...  temperaturehigh  weekend  crimecount
2     13      7  2014  ...            27.44        0          89
4     21      9  2014  ...            24.15        0          66
8     10     11  2014  ...            16.27        0          76
9      5     11  2014  ...            17.76        0         101
11    10      7  2014  ...            28.06        0          99
..   ...    ...   ...  ...              ...      ...         ...
382   10      8  2014  ...            30.51        0         119
389   21     11  2014  ...             2.65        1         110
390    4      7  2014  ...            23.37        1          84
391    8      8  2014  ...            27.98        1          97
393    3      8  2014  ...            24.50        0          80

[184 rows x 16 columns]
```

Comment: `seems that I am using OR instead of AND, because I do not get any values for month=6 (also not for 2014) and no values for year=2015 at all, so also not for other months in 2015.` - do you use `train= df[(df.month!=6) | (df.year!=2015)]` ? What is question?

Comment: Looks like you are doing everything correct, what types have `year` and `month` in `print(df.dtypes)`?

Answer (score 2):

Just elaborating on Francis answer, you're looking at the condition in the wrong manner.

You want all the data except for a certain month in a certain year. So, when would the value be "right"? If either of them is not in the month or year.

So, this is exactly the `OR` condition.

Another way to look at it - you have conditions `X` and `Y`.
You're "wrong" when both `X` and `Y` exist, or simply `X & Y`.
So, when are you "right"? When `!(X & Y)` == `!X | !Y`.

It's your choice how you tackle this, but you can do something like:

`train = df[(df.month != 6) | (df.year != 2015)]`
or
`train = df[~((df.month == 6) & (df.year == 2015))]`
Which are equivalent

Comment: Meant to edit my response and explain the logic but this does it perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use | for OR as suspected.

```
    >>> df = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2014,2015,2015],'month':[6,5,6]})
    >>> df
       year  month
    0  2014      6
    1  2015      5
    2  2015      6
    >>> train = df[(df['year']!=2015) | (df['month']!=6)]
    >>> train
       year  month
    0  2014      6
    1  2015      5
```

Comment: This is exactly what OP does not want, OP is suggesting that it looks like the filter is applying or, while OP wants AND

Comment: @Erfan you're looking at it wrong, if you want to filter out all but a certain condition, then you can think of when the condition is wrong is when both exist, so the rest is when either or them exist it's okay

Comment: @Erfan take a look at my answer, it's more elaborated. It's exactly what OP wants, when you look at it in a logical view

Comment: I have edited my response with example input/output

Comment: I see now, I misunderstood the explanation